# Angular 8 TypeError: Cannot add property 2, object is not extensible

Tags: angular, rxjs, cesiumjs

I have an Angular 8 app using RxJS and angular-cesium that is in production for the past 6 months, and I had no issues.

In the past week the app works fine when I run `ng serve` locally, but when I build it and deploy I am now getting this error when I make certain actions:

```
core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property 2, object is not extensible
at Array.push (<anonymous>)
at l._subscribe (Subject.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:97)
at l._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:12)
at l._trySubscribe (Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:42)
at l._trySubscribe (Subject.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:81)
at l.subscribe (Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:28)
at je.call (app.component.ts:41)
at d.subscribe (Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:23)
at IF.<anonymous> (lines-layer.component.ts:122)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

The start of the above stack trace (`lines-layer.component.ts`) changes every time I build, but the last 6 lines (starting from `Observable.js`) stay the same.
I also get the same error when I serve the `dist` folder locally.

I've been debugging for a couple of days now and I've gotten nowhere... did anyone get this error too?

Comment: Try running the Angular app in your local machine with this command: `ng serve --aot --prod`. Repeat the same set of actions that is causing the problem now. This should give you more insight into the error(s) you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea why this happened, but I guessed (correctly) that it had to do with some library I was using, so I updated them all to the latest version (including Angular to version 9) and it did the trick.